# Can't run an app from another app

Tags: android, android-xml

I have this xml code:

```
<Preference android:title="@string/build_number" android:key="build_number" android:summary="@string/device_info_default" style="?android:preferenceInformationStyle">
    <intent android:targetPackage="com.gigabytekeys.jkdevinfo" android:action="android.intent.action.MAIN" android:targetClass="com.gigabytekeys.jkdevinfo.ChangeLogActivity" />
</Preference>
```

The problem is, it won't launch the com.gigabytekeys.jkdevinfo application. Whenever I click that item, nothing happens. How can I make it work?

I'm just new to android development and I am not familiar with the way that devs do things. So, please be kind to me. :)

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on what com.gigabytekeys.jkdevinfo's manifest declares for that `Activity`  If it is not exported (i.e. an internal Activity) then you will not able to send it an `Intent` to start the `Activity`.  What do you see in the logcat output?

Comment: Thanks for answering... :D However, I don't see anything in my logcat output. It seems to be clean, very clean. :/ How do I make an activity exported? My ChangeLogActivity in manifest is like: `<activity android:name=".ChangeLogActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" ><intent-filter><action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /></intent-filter>` Does that make the activity able to start it from the other apps?
        </activity>`

Comment: Yes, by adding an <intent-filter> tag to the activity in the manifest it is automatically exported.  Double check your package and fully qualified activity name.  As a test, you could try to manually create the intent in code and verify you can send it, just to rule out a problem with the preference.